# Trying to send a message from a html window that is in the extension package to the content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I added a new (popup) [window](https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Customizable-Popup-Browser-Windows-with-jQuery-Popup-Window-Plugin.jpg)

not the popup.html you register in the manifest.

the user puts information in the window and when they click on a  button the information needs to be send to the content.js script.

The html of the (popup) window is in the extension package so there isn't any need to add a "externally_connectable" object in the manifest.json
and it isn't part of another extension so you don't use the sendMessageExternal method.

## Manifest.json

```
    {
"name": "extension name",
"version": "0.1",
"options_page": "settings.html",
"manifest_version": 2,
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js":["jquery.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Default title",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/logo16.png",
        "32": "images/logo32.png",
        "48": "images/logo48.png",
        "128": "images/logo128.png"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "images/logo16.png",
    "32": "images/logo32.png",
    "48": "images/logo48.png",
    "128": "images/logo128.png"
        }
    }
```

## Content.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(req, sender, senderres){
            if(req.succes == true){
            // Do stuff...
        }
    });
```

## js file that is referenced in the (popup) window

```
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("BtnFinish").addEventListener('click',
    function(){
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({succes: true});
      self.close();
    });
  }
```

This is the code I used in the background.js to create the (popup) window

```
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("form.html"),
        type: "popup"
    });
```

I do receive any error messages.
The button works it activates every bit of code, but the content.js does not receive anything.

If you need anymore information or did I forget something, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage) there is a clause in there:

> Note that extensions cannot send messages to content scripts using this method. To send messages to content scripts, use tabs.sendMessage.

Which means that you'll have to do something like this:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true}, (windows) => {
  windows.forEach((window) => {
    window.tabs.forEach((tab) => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {succes: true});
    });
  });
});
```

You'll need the `tabs` permission in order to do this.
I'm using `chrome.windows.getAll` because it seems that you're trying to send a message to a content script in another window not a different tab of the same window.